# Ui Router tabs with routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router and I need to hook up tabs where the url changes as well. So for example, I have a page with 3 sublinks:

1. **Customer Overview** (templates/customer.overview.html): example.com/customer/:id/overview
2. **Customer Settings** (templates/customer.settings.html): example.com/customer/:id/settings
3. **Customer Contact Info** (templates/customer.contact.html): example.com/customer/:id/contact

All three of these pages should be injected into one main `customers.main.html` page that includes the links.

My states are defined as follows:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('customer', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/customer',
      templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
        return $templateCache.get('templates/customer.overview.html');
      }
    })
    .state('customer.overview', {
      url:'/:id/overview',
      controller: ''
      templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
        return $templateCache.get('templates/customer.settings.html');
      }
    })
    .state('customer.contact', {
      url:'/:id/contact',
      controller: ''
      templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
        return $templateCache.get('templates/customer.contact.html');
      }
    });
```

And I have a `customers.main.html` page:

```
<div class="tabs" ng-controller="TabsCtrl as tabs">
   <a ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ui-sref='{{tab.route}}' ng-bind="tab.label">
</div>
```

**TabsCtrl**

```
angular.module('customers')
  .controller('TabsCtrl', [
    function() {

    var self = this;

    self.tabs = [
      {
        label: 'Overview',
        route: 'customer.overview',
        active: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Settings',
        route: 'customer.settings',
        active: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Contact',
        route: 'customer.contact',
        active: false
      }
    ];

    self.selectedTab = self.tabs[0];
  }
]);
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working correctly. The `ui-sref` directive when I click always resolves to something like: `/customers//settings`. It's not picking up the `:id`.

Any help?

Comment: did you try using the element inspector to check the href is correctly being rendered from the ui-sref in the browser? from the error and the double slash in the link, i think there is something funny going on with this

Comment: You are missing `,`s after the `controller` declaration for your states. But @pankajparkar is correct in that you aren't passing an `id` to your states (he's missing `{}` in his answer's syntax). You can see the difference between your `ui-sref` and [ones with params here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not passing `customerId` in your `ui-sref` function so that the `ui-sref` would be `ui-sref="customer.overview(id: 1)"` , 1 could dynamically change on basis of `customerId`

```
<div class="tabs" ng-controller="TabsCtrl as tabs">
   <a ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ui-sref="{{tab.route+'({ id:' + 1 + '})'}}" ng-bind="tab.label">
</div>
```

[**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mvskYeMCImNBgz5TVDon?p=preview) take a look how I created `ui-sref` for `contact`

Comment: Thanks this is definitely the reason. However, I'm getting syntax errors when I try and use `ui-sref="{{tab.route+'(id:' + 1 + ')'}}"`

Comment: @cusejuice thats my bad `ui-sref` parameter should have wrap in curly brace `{}` like `ui-sref="{{tab.route+'({ id:' + 1 + '})'}}"`...also look at plunkr which I've attached

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this ,i think you have to use $scope in your controller like this: 
         $scope.tabs= [{.......},{.......},{......}];   // .....is your data
 And then you can use ui-sref="{{tab.route}}"

I had same probleme and i solved it with          href="#/myUrl/{{idOfUser}}//overview" 
You can try this too but you have yo give idOfUser and use full path. I hope you understand what i mean .